# socket.on('disconnect', function () { }; works but nothing displays in the browser when a user disconnects

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, node.js-connect

I am very new to node and newer to websockets. Using the following code, the message correctly prints in the console but no message is displayed in the browser window whenever a user closes his window(disconnect).

```
var io = require('socket.io'),
connect = require('connect');

var app = connect().use(connect.static('public')).listen(3000);
var chat_room = io.listen(app);

chat_room.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
socket.emit('entrance', {message: 'Welcome to the chat room!'});

socket.on('disconnect', function  () {
console.log("A chatter just Disconnected.");
chat_room.sockets.emit('exit', {message: 'A chatter has disconnected.'});
});

chat_room.sockets.emit('entrance', {message: 'A new chatter is online.'});
});
```

I am using chrome browser.　Is there any mistake in the code? Any help will be appreciated as I am only learning.

Comment: Do you get the `console.log`?

Comment: Yes.I did get the console.log

Comment: Can you show the client side code for `exit`?

Comment: The client side code goes like this:<html>
<head>
<script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

 socket.on('entrance', function  (data) {
  document.write('<p>' + data.message + '</p>');
 });

 socket.on('exit', function  (data) {
  document.write('<p>' + data.message + '</p>');
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply rewriting the code solved the problem for me. I do not see any differences though. Just glad that it worked!